# C# delegate event dont send class instance as parameter for reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, event-handling, delegates, anonymous-function

I want to fire a general Event on my gameManager containing the player that has died. Inside the player class, I have defined a parameterless event OnDied. The GameManager subscribes to each player to fire the even containg the one that died. But the main problem is that I cannot unsubscribe the delegate at a later point of the game, eg. when reloading the scene, because of the anonymous delegate.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public delegate void OnPlayerDiedEvent(Player target); public event OnPlayerDiedEvent OnPlayerDied;
    public List<Player> players;

    private void Start(){
        foreach(Player p in players){
            p.OnDied += ()=> { if(OnPlayerDied != null) OnPlayerDied(p); };
        }
    }
}
```

I could have defined the players OnDied event to take itself (= OnDied(this)), but this does not look right, because when you subscribe to an event, you have in fact a reference to the class instance (in this case, GameManager knows the players),
just like this:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public delegate void OnDiedEvent(Player _this); public event OnDiedEvent OnDied;
    public void Die(){ //call whener player should die
        if(OnDied != null)
            OnDied(this); //<-- is odd, better to use System.Action OnDied;
    }
}
```

And Inside GameManager I used a wrapper method *HandleOnPlayerDied(Player target)*.

```
private void Start(){
    foreach(Player p in players){
        p.OnDied += HandleOnPlayerDied;
    }
}

void HandleOnPlayerDied(Player target){
    if(OnPlayerDied != null)
        OnPlayerDied(target);
}

void OnDestroy(){
    foreach(Player p in players){
        p.OnDied -= HandleOnPlayerDied;
    }
}
```

Again, this approach works, but I am quite unhappy of putting the class instance as parameter of its event, just to keep a reference of the current died player.
A very dumb way is to check all players alive-state every frame and comparing to their previous state. Then there is a reference to the player that died, but this is overthrowing the principle of using events and also unefficient due to every frame checking.

Comment: Interesting situation. What is the question? If you mean to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your last code block should be written as an answer below with an explanation of how it answers the question.

Comment: The last code block is a way of accomplishing to get the global event in the GameManager working, but I thought sending the player instance is not clean code as subscribers will already know the instance. For example if the player has a weapon and it has a referwence to its owner, and the wapon should detach when he died, its subscription will contain again the player as parameter: private Player myPlayer; void Awake(){ myPlayer.OnDied += DropWeapon; } void DropWeapon(Player _thisPlayer){ Detach(); } //_thisPlayer is useless since a class reference myPlayer already is defined in class Weapon

Comment: The event "a player is dead" has the information who is dead, is acceptable. Why is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first

```
private void Start(){
    foreach(Player p in players){
        p.OnDied += ()=> { if(OnPlayerDied != null) OnPlayerDied(p); };
    }
}
```

will never work as expected. Because of the lambda expression you can not unsubscribe as you already noted but even worse: due to Variable Capture / Closure in lambda expressions you would get the event all called with the last value assigned to `p`!

---

Now your second approach is okey-ish. But as you say your manager class needs to know each instance of `Player` beforehand.

What about rather a `static` event like

(in general for Single-Parameter events I prefer to directly use `Action` instead of a custom delegate type)

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Since you pass in the according reference anyway
    // this event can as well simply be static right away
    public static event Action<Player> OnDied;

    public void Die()
    {
        OnDied?.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action<Player> OnPlayerDied;

    private void Start()
    {
        Player.OnDied += HandlePlayerDied;
    }

    private void HandlePlayerDied(Player player)
    {
        OnPlayerDied?.Invoke(player);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        Player.OnDied -= HandlePlayerDied;
    }
}
```

This way all the manager needs to know is there is an event this type can invoke and I get a `Player` reference along with it.

Note that of course this additional event of the `GameManager` is basically completely redundant if there is nothing else done except forwarding this event. You could as well directly attach all listeners to `Player.OnDied` instead.

Comment: ooh, interesting idea making `OnDied` static.

Comment: But what about other classes that need to listen for a specific players death? When it is static, each player that dies will trigger this event. Therefore it should always be checked if it is the wanted player eg. void HandleOnPlayerDied(Player player){ if(player != myPlayer) return; //Do other stuff } This seems like unneccesary checks. And redefining the event in GameManger seems redundant as it is invoking right after the static event has been invoked. My aim was to make a parameterless callback of the player class and a managing class should fire the event, containing the player.

Comment: @McMidas no .. that is why you pass in the Player which died ;) The `HandlePlayerDied` is just like yours in the global manager class .. it isn't related to one specific `Player`. Actually of course it is completely redundant and not necessary at all of you do nothing else in there except forwarding the event. In this case you would rather directly attach your listeners to the `Player.OnDied` instead ;)